# Play Youtube DASH audio

Tags: html, cordova, audio, youtube, youtube-dl

I have recently posted a similar question, but now my basic conditions have completely changed.

That is what I am doing: 
1. I have a website which shall be used in a Cordova application later
2. The website gets the audio stream from a specific youtube video(via a php implementation of youtube-dl):

```
extension: m4a
resolution: audio only
note: DASH audio
URL(will expire quick):https://r13---sn-vgqs7ne6.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?fexp=900720%2C907263%2C912525%2C934954%2C936104%2C938028%2C9406715%2C9407115%2C9408086%2C9408107%2C9408347%2C9408467%2C9408704%2C9412490%2C9412714%2C947233%2C948124%2C948703%2C948813%2C951703%2C952612%2C952626%2C952634%2C952635%2C952637%2C957201&key=yt5&ip=107.178.194.119&lmt=1428663266962903&ms=au&source=youtube&mv=m&dur=197.856&id=o-AB3KhNJDzXuP4VTfavUoRPJSjbB-2BOUGQ8ds7gqVYqi&mm=31&itag=140&clen=3177020&sver=3&gir=yes&pl=26&mt=1430138392&mime=audio%2Fmp4&expire=1430160056&signature=326D41C981B841BE3099AF396860591FF3ACE1EE.A0D0CCFB217AFF3D748650661ABE5F1403991167&upn=3oybEKIlXw8&keepalive=yes&requiressl=yes&ipbits=0&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Ckeepalive%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&ratebypass=yes
```

3. I now want to play the audio, here I have two options:

a)using HTML5 Audio Tag - However, the tag needs to load in Chrome and Safari for a very long time until it starts [I have tested the same URL in VLC Player where it starts immediately, thus it is not due to low latency][In fact it is due to the big buffer the audio tag loads before starting since it loads roughly 5MB before it starts]

b)I use an iOS native audio instance - Unfortunately the avaudioplayer does not support DASH-Audio

Does anybody know a way to deliver a quick audio response for my application? As native iOS code or (better) as HTML5 solution. Because having to wait a couple of seconds for the audio to start is a very poor user experience.

In addition, the audio URL has no file extension. However, what would it actually be?

I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Did you find a solution?